# rspec-guard detecting changes in spec folder, but not lib folder

Tags: guard

Like the title says, it detects changes in spec folder, not in lib folder.

### Guardfile

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  require "guard/rspec/dsl"
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # Feel free to open issues for suggestions and improvements

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec
  watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_files)

  # Ruby files
  ruby = dsl.ruby
  files = ruby.lib_files
  save_path = '/data/sites/scripts/sw_scripts/ruby/files.txt'
  File.write(save_path, ruby.lib_files.inspect)
  dsl.watch_spec_files_for(ruby.lib_files)
end
```

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'thor'
gem 'rmagick'

group :development do
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec', ">=3.0"
end
```

### What I did:

- read lots of Guard documentation - it's hopelessly outdated, Guardfile has changed it's syntax (it contains some regexes while there was no regexes in my autogenerated Guardfile, links to 3+ year old tutorials etc)
- put puts statement in `Guardfile` to see what is `ruby.lib_files`
- it didn't work so I used `File.write(path, ruby.lib_files.inspect)`
- file contained regexp

So I went into irb and confirmed that regexp is correct, it matches all lib files  from `Dir['**/*']`

```
r = /^(lib\/.+)\.rb$/

`pwd`
=> "correct_dir\n"

files = Dir['**/*']
=> ** 149 files **

puts files.select { |f| r =~ f }
=> ** 36 files (snippet) **
lib/gallery_util/gallery_source.rb
lib/gallery_util/legacy_gallery_updater.rb
lib/gallery/specs/specs.rb
lib/gallery/specs/report.rb
lib/gallery/specs/universal_property.rb
lib/gallery/front_page_creator.rb
...
```

So all files are recognized, but when I run guard for any of the lib files it doesn't work at all. I get this output when I run guard in debug mode:

```
09:55:44 - DEBUG - Interactor was stopped or killed
09:55:44 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
09:55:44 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_end executed for Guard::RSpec
09:55:44 - DEBUG - Start interactor
```

Only thing that comes to mind is that guard for some reason doesn't look into lib folder recursively. I doubt that possible, why would anyone decide that?

Other thing that it depends on location of .git.
.git is 2 folders above this one (because this is collection of independent scripts that work togather and I want them in 1 repo, not 5+)

How to fix it? How to force guard to watch lib folder recursively?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that guard needs spec folders structure to match identically the lib folder structure. It can't figure out matching spec if you have files

```
lib/gallery/front_page.rb
spec/front_page_spec.rb
```

No you have to create it like this:

```
lib/gallery/front_page.rb
spec/lib/gallery/front_page_spec.rb
```

I assume this would work as well (but haven't tried it)

```
lib/gallery/front_page.rb
spec/gallery/front_page_spec.rb
```

To guard maintainers: surely would be nice if that was documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Guard and spent the last two days to understand why RSpec doesn't start when a `'something_test.rb'` file is modified and saved.
Digging deep into the code, I have found a method in Inspectors::BaseInspector

```
    def _select_only_spec_files(paths)
       spec_files = _collect_files("*[_.]spec.rb")
```

which forces test files to be named `'..._spec.rb'`. According to the documentation of Guard/Dsl :

> The watch method tells Guard which changed files the plugin should respond to.

In my opinion this hard-coding of '_spec.rb' is in contradiction with the freedom that `watch` gives to you.

Also I don't like the code in your Guardfile, which is generated by `guard init rspec`. The intention of the authors is certainly good, it allows newcomers to quickly start automating RSpec tests. But one don't master what's going on behind the scene, and it seems to be your case.

This is my Guardfile with a patch to redefine SimpleInspector#paths :

```
directories %w[ lib spec ]

guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec' do
    require 'guard/rspec'
    require "guard/rspec/inspectors/simple_inspector.rb"
    module ::Guard
        class RSpec < Plugin
            module Inspectors
                class SimpleInspector < BaseInspector
                    def paths(paths)
                        # please don't clear modified files correctly detected
                        # by watch but whose name doesn't end with '_spec.rb'
                        paths # return input without modification
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

        # test files
    watch(/^spec\/.*_test\.rb$/)

        # source files
#    watch(%r|^lib/(?<path>.+)\.rb$|) { | m | "spec/#{m[:path]}_test.rb" }
#       *** same as ***        
    watch(/^lib\/(.+)\.rb$/) { | m | "spec/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
end
```

This is a temporary workaround I hope, at least it lets me define a `watch` statement the way I want, which corresponds to my existing test files.

The first `watch` detects changed RSpec `'..._test.rb'` files in the `spec` directory. The second `watch` detects a changed source file in the `lib` directory or one of its subdirectories, and transforms its name in the block so that RSpec will be presented a `'spec/..._test.rb'` file.

This way you get rid of any constraint and can master your own regexp. You could even manipulate the path in the block, if the hierarchy of the tests doesn't match the one of the sources : why not

```
watch(/^abd\/def\/(.+)\.rb$/) { | m | "anywhere\/you\/like\/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
```

And I can reassure you : guard-2.14.1 on my Mac perfectly detects changed files even deep inside the `lib` folder hierarchy.

HTH

PS : I don't have bundle, but you can replace `cmd: 'rspec'` by `cmd: "bundle exec rspec"` in the guard command.

Some console output to convince you it works (the test file is empty) :

```
21:08:29 - DEBUG - Start interactor
21:08:29 - DEBUG - Command execution: stty -g 2>/dev/null
[1] guard(main)> _[Guard] in guard.rb #async_queue_add ch={:modified=>["lib/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me.rb"], :added=>[], :removed=>[]}
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Interactor was stopped or killed
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Command execution: stty  2>/dev/null
_[Guard] //1 in Runner#run_on_changes mod=["lib/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me.rb"] add=[] rem=[]
    ...
_[Guard] //3 in Runner#run_on_changes ... plugin Guard::RSpec yielded, types={[:run_on_modifications, :run_on_changes, :run_on_change]=>["lib/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me.rb"], [:run_on_additions, :run_on_changes, :run_on_change]=>[], ...
_[Guard] //3+ plugin=#<Guard::RSpec @name=rspec @group=#<Guard::Group @name=default @options={}> @watchers=[#<Guard::Watcher:0x0..., @pattern=#<Guard::Watcher::Pattern::Matcher:0x007fbdca22d780 @matcher=/^spec\/.*_test\.rb$/>>, ..., @pattern=#<Guard::Watcher::Pattern::Matcher:0x007fbdca22d528 @matcher=/^lib\/(.+)\.rb$/>>]
...
_[Guard] //5 in Runner#run_on_changes ... match_result=["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]
...
task=run_on_modifications
_[Guard] /+-+ in Runner#_supervise pl=Guard::RSpec, t=run_on_modifications, args=[["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]]
...
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_modifications_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
_[Guard] §§§ in Plugin self.notify gp=Guard::RSpec, ev=run_on_modifications_begin, args=[["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]]
_[Guard] /+-+ in Runner#_supervise about to plugin.send task=run_on_modifications, args=[["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]]
_[RSpec] &&&& in RSpec#run_on_modifications paths=["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]
_[RSpec] &&&& in RSpec#run_on_modifications about to runner.run
_[RSpec] ))) in RSpec::Runner#run paths=["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"] inspector=#<Guard::RSpec::Inspectors::SimpleInspector:0x007fbdca2351b0>
_[RSpec] ))) in RSpec::Runner#run after inspector ["spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb"]
21:08:36 - INFO - Running: spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb
_[RSpec] ))) in RSpec::Runner#_run
_[RSpec] ))) in RSpec::Runner#_run command=rspec
...
_[RSpec] ))) in RSpec::Runner#_really_run cmd=rspec -f documentation -r /Users/b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rspec2/gems/guard-rspec-4.7.3/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb ...  spec/antlr4/ruby_static/listeners/please_check_me_test.rb
...
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Command execution: ...                
Finished in 0.00042 seconds (files took 0.10208 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
...
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Guard::RSpec: RSpec command spec ... exited with: 0

...
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Start interactor
21:08:36 - DEBUG - Command execution: stty -g 2>/dev/null
```